# Is it possible 'step into' a method to make changes when needed

Tags: python, code-reuse

I’m working on a Python script that accesses number of websites. I don’t think writing a whole class for each website is a feasible option, so I am looking for a way to reduce the code and re-use code as much as I can and write it as efficiently as I can. Although the website share same or similar engine (e.g. Wordpress), they often differ with slight details like cookie names, changed URL paths (e.g. example.com/signin.php and example2.com/login.php), data names and values for POST requests, and so on.

In most cases I could use variables, but sometimes I need to find extra data from retrieved url in the middle of method to continue, so that means adding few lines of code that needs to be processed before proceeding. I found that possible solution for me could theoretically be to use superclasses. But I couldn’t find any information how to actually ‘step into’ a method to make changes. To better illustrate my point, take a look at this example

```
class Wordpress(object):
    def login(self):
        # Do some stuff here


    def newentry(self):
        # Code to check if I'm logged in code
        # and do bunch of other stuff
        #
        # Retrieve a page that *** sometimes contain important information 
        # in which case must be processed to continue! ***
        data = {'name'  : title,
                'message' : message,
                'icon' : iconid}
        # Post new entry here
```

As I already commented in the example above in some cases I need to make adjustement just inside a method itself, add snippet of code, or change value of the variable or value in the dictionary, etc.. How can I achieve that, if it's even possible? Maybe my perception of superclasses is way off and they aren't really for what I think they are.

Maybe there's other way I haven't thought of. Feel free to post your own ideas how you would solve this problem. I am looking forward to your replies. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just call some `process` function from the main method, process can do whatever you want it to do, and you can even override it in derived classes e.g.

```
class WordPress(object):
    def newentry(self):
        data = get_data()
        data = process_data(data)

        # do moe generi cthings

    def process_data(self):
        return data
```